# Change the x_axis from numbers to months

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have the following plot:
[image 1 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqkdt.png)
the x_axis are day's year in numbers (from 1 to 365)

I want to change the x_axis to something like this:
[image 2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouItH.png)

How can I do that?

Comment: Try to come up with a [MCVE]. Also show what have you tried so far? Do you have dates in your dataframe that you are using to plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data
x = np.array([0,15,30,45,60,75,90]) # Days
y = np.array([20,25,21,22,23,20,29]) # Temperature

# Labels
first_day_of_month = np.array([0,31,59,89]) # First day of each month
my_xticks = ['January','February','March','April']
plt.xticks(first_day_of_month, my_xticks)

#Plot
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]